# Default role for ActiveModel mass assignments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

Given a model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email
  attr_accessible :active, as: :backend
end
```

It's now possible to mass assign as follows:

```
User.new name: 'Peter', email: 'pete@foo.bar'
User.new { name: 'Peter', email: 'pete@foo.bar', active: true }, as: :backend
```

I'm using the active_admin gem for the backend which falls back to generic controller actions unless you specify an action explicitly. In other words: I'd have to write an explicit action whenever a mass assignment is made in order to add the "as: :backend" option. Not nice.

One solution is of course to reverse things and add "as: :frontend" in the frontend actions which are all declared explicitly already.

But maybe there's a way to set the "as" option globally e.g. in a before filter for the backend route namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'm dropping this plan and sanitize the mass assignments in the frontend with the strong_passwords gem instead. There's a good chance this gem will be integrated into Rails 4 and it's a nice replacement for the attr_accessible with roles hassle.

As a side note: The README of the strong_passwords gem didn't really cut it for me, but Ryan Bates has done a very helpful Railscasts episode (371-strong-parameters) on it.